# Is there any why to show loading screen while fetching API data using getStaticProps in next js?

Tags: next.js

Is there any why to show loading screen while fetching API data using getStaticProps in next js?

```js
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const data = await fetch(API_END_POINT);
  
  return {
    props: {
      data
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to show loading screen? You are not doing ISR in the code you've shown, so the `getStaticProps` function will only be called during build.

Comment: how to do it with ISR,

Answer (score 1):

`getStaticProps` runs at build time so there is no need for the loading screen since the data will always be available (statically generated).
However, there is another option: [`getStaticPaths`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticpaths-static-generation)

In combination with [fallback pages](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#fallback-pages).
Basically there is a mix of static and server rendered pages (but there is no request and response objects)

```js
// pages/posts/[id].js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

function Post({ post }) {
  const router = useRouter()

  // If the page is not yet generated, this will be displayed
  // initially until getStaticProps() finishes running
  if (router.isFallback) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }

  // Render post...
}

// This function gets called at build time
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  return {
    // Only `/posts/1` and `/posts/2` are generated at build time
    paths: [{ params: { id: '1' } }, { params: { id: '2' } }],
    // Enable statically generating additional pages
    // For example: `/posts/3`
    fallback: true,
  }
}

// This also gets called at build time
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  // params contains the post `id`.
  // If the route is like /posts/1, then params.id is 1
  const res = await fetch(`https://.../posts/${params.id}`)
  const post = await res.json()

  // Pass post data to the page via props
  return {
    props: { post },
    // Re-generate the post at most once per second
    // if a request comes in
    revalidate: 1,
  }
}

export default Post
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure to add getStaticPaths with fallback equal to true. See example below

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
    return {
        paths: [],
        fallback: true,
    }
}
```

then in the component(example a post page component), add a check if router isFallback is true. See below example

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

function Post({ post }) {
  const router = useRouter()

  // If the page is not yet generated, this will be displayed
  // initially until getStaticProps() finishes running
  if (router.isFallback) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }

  // Render post...
}
```